# Need Mongo query to get the count of multiple fields in a documents from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo documents like below :

```
{
    "a": "test",
    "b": "test", 
    "c": "test", 
    "d": "test", 
}

{
    "a": "test",
    "b": "test", 
    "d": "test", 
}

{
    "a": "notest",
    "b": "test", 
    "c": "test", 
    "d": "test", 
}
```

I want to pull all the documents where  `a="test"`

Then the result should be like the (Overall count and total count of each fields)

```
{
    "totalcount" : 3,
    "b-count" : 2,
    "c-count" : 1,
    "d-count" : 1
}
```

Comment: what is the totalcount, is that total documents in collection or total documents that match to $match ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have todo an aggregate (the alternative is calling 3 different find query's and combining the results), it should be roughly like this:

```
db.getCollection("").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
               a: "test"
            }
        },
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : 0.0, 
                "b" : 1.0, 
                "c" : 1.0, 
                "d" : 1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : {
                "tmp" : {
                    "$objectToArray" : "$$ROOT"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$tmp"
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$tmp.k", 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : null, 
                "results" : {
                    "$push" : {
                        "label" : "$_id", 
                        "count" : "$count"
                    }
                }, 
                "total" : {
                    "$sum" : "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

The results aren't exactly in the format which you asked for but that can be easily changed using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and $addFields, however i feel that it is redundant to do so.

Comment: Good use of `$objectToArray`.   It's not a well known operator but super useful for turning lvals (keys) Into rvals (values).